# Mahjong Checker

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, game

Mahjong is a tabletop game played using tiles. It features three "number" suits (pins, sous, mans, represented as `p`, `s` and `m`) from 1 to 9, and one "honor" suit `z` of seven distinct tiles. Note that contrary to western card games, tiles are not unique.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5595067/33491135-4ac4b4e6-d6f4-11e7-8df6-038f113fcef9.png]

To complete a hand and win, the 13 tiles in your hand are combined with 1 newly drawn tile and must result in one of the following winning configurations:

- 4 sets and 1 pair, self-explanatory
- seven pairs, where all pairs are distinct (twice the same pair wouldn't qualify)
- kokushi musou: one of each of the 1 and 9 of each number suit, one of every seven honors, the remaining tile forming a pair (e.g. `19m19p19s11234567z`)

A pair is any of the two same tiles: `11m`, `33s`, `44p`, `55z`, etc.

A set consists of 3 tiles of the same suit. It can either be a run: 3 number tiles (p, s or m) in a connected run like `123s` or `234s`, but not `1m 2p 3s` or `234z`; or a triplet of any suit, not necessarily numbers, like `111z`, `222m`.

So honor tiles (non-numbers, represented by `z`) can only form pairs or triplets, but not runs. `567z` is not a set, `555z` is a valid set, `55z` is a valid pair.

A single tile can only be counted as part of one set or pair: there is no sharing or reusing.

Given a sorted hand of 13 tiles and one tile, check whether the 14 tiles make up a completed hand.

### Input & Output

- You are given a sequence of numbers and letters, a space, then a tile of a number and a letter
- Output `True`/`1` if the set is a match, else `False`/`0`

### Others:

- You are allowed to input the sequence and tile+letter as a list/array

### Test Cases:

Truthy

```
222888m444p2277z 7z
234m45789p45688s 6p
11m4477p8899s116z 6z
19m19p19s1234567z 6z
123345567789m3p 3p
```

Falsey

```
1122335778899m 1m
888m55s11222333z 4z
234m2233445566p 4p
19m139p19s123567z 4z
11m4477p8899s666z 6z
```

Credits to Unihedron for the [puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/completed-mahjong-hands)!

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins!

Comment: Can we take input as `1m 2m 3m` etc?

Comment: yes you can although im not sure it that changes the challenge too much

Comment: Borderline dupe of [mahjong solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/39896/78410), since the main task is to check if a 14-tile set is a winning hand (the linked challenge just requires to do the same thing for every possible 14th tile). FYI, there has been [four different mahjong-related challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=mahjong+is%3Aq) already.

Comment: Since points (fan / han) related rules are not considered in this question. Is there any reason to place the last tile independently from the others?

Comment: The description of kokushi musou is a bit confusion. Someone may read as it requires the last tile form the pair (aka the requirement of 13 waiting kokushi musou).

Comment: May I assume the input is ordered, as `1m`, `2m`, ..., `9m`, `1p`, ..., `9p`, `1s`, ..., `9s`, `1z`, ..., `7z`?

Comment: As a note: The rule for 7-pairs may be quite different in different mahjong rules. Some  rules doesn't consider 7-pairs as a winning hands at all. Some others allow 7 pairs but disallow 4 same tile in it. And some allow 4 same tile in it and score it as same as other 7 pairs. There are also some rules score more points if you get 4 same tile in 7-pairs (with another name _deluxe 7-pairs_).

Comment: @Bubbler The linked question have a slightly different rules: This one includes 7 pairs and 13 orphans while that one don't. The [shantin question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199202/count-the-shantens) seems using a similar rule, while it could be more complex than the one you linked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>248</s> <s>246</s> 245 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.sort().every((t,i)=>t==s[i^1]&t!=s[n=12,i+2])|A(s)|[...new Set(s)].length>n
A=y=>y.some(t=>R(y,t,t,t)|t[n+=t>'2'&t<'9'&t[1]<A,1]<A&R(y,t,t[0]-1+t[1],t[0]-2+t[1]))|y[0]==y[1]&!y[2]
R=(s,p,q,r,z=0,k=s.filter(y=>y!=p||z++))=>p?z&&R(k,q,r):A(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDbjpswEH3nK5wXsAXrjc29u6bKSz9g95HSCCVOli4QBzupoOy3Z8ekVVVZGs2ZOWfOeH7W11rvhkaZh/60l7eDuGlRaKpPg8GEyqscRoxN0BBRGCF02fxglWtWkPWC8aDxeUXmDdZkLimlvfyFXqUBWNFW9kfzVvTORoyiGGFkJ7ERxQseA2MfmU3Z@8IUHvdc8@zlEEtWPW8CG9w/vHJdPTDfNu45X3JC5hGQECMAdzWWvHJeBNaBCs7BEExiHbwLTQ9Na@SArf9KqHmefJ/AT9TXyYX575ZLvtjtb0/OIM@XZpDYO2iP0EHW@29NK1/HfofXgXcxh2wpq7beSfxI/cdjAKf67SB0rQdkkEBl9QRI/yPh73ufYEqAivDW7kbuCoTstVRFu1rhLZyWqot@w1v/TIid8bHE3anXp1bS9nSEnx2wsc0PcuOcZ1nWRVGkOE/TCaWTw8Ooi@I0y1UUJ1mmUaIcxoCTpirL8lwzlkwomRyWdyxXDAogiZP0XuQhAEAwoAsVCq2YQzGGCqg7xDrHesaxtg3ohBOK7rYWRVadKBSpxSD867AYAO@/VZJkWeUT)

Every answer is in js...

`f` is the main function, relying on `A` modifying `n` for non-1919191234567 check

`A` check if it's 3+3+3+3+2

`R` removes some triplet and go on `A`ing

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (SpiderMonkey), 807 bytes

```js
[a,[b,c]]=readline(j=m=0).split` `
d=[...h='mpsz'].map(k=>!~(i=a.indexOf(k))?'':a.slice([j,j=i+1][0],i))
d[i=h.indexOf(c)]=[...d[i]].concat(b).sort().join``
if(~(''+d).search`(1+9+,){3}1+2+3+4+5+6+7`|d.every(k=>/^(?:(.)\1(?!\1))*$/.test(k)))print(1);else A:{a=/(.)(\1*)/g;e=d.pop();while(n=a.exec(e))if(!n[2]){print(0);break A}else if(n[2].length==1)if(m){print(0);break A}else m=1
f=l=>{if(!l.length)return;var[h,n,b]=l;if((a=n-h)>1)return 1;i=l.indexOf(+n+1);if(a==1)return!~i?1:f(l.slice(2,i)+l.slice(i+1));if(~i){c=l.slice(1,i)+l.slice(i+1,i=l.indexOf(+n+2))+l.slice(i+1);if(~i&&!f(c))return}return n-b||f(l.slice(3))};m=d.filter(k=>{if(!(c=k.length%3))return f(k);else if(c==2){r=/(.)\1/g;while(n=r.exec(k))if(!f(k.slice(0,n.index)+k.slice(r.lastIndex)))return m=1,0}return 1}).length?0:m
print(m?1:0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJdj9owEHznVwSpvXjPwcSBFkpk0D32qT8gpMIk5mJwTOSk9I6vv04dklD1pD56d3ZmdsdbfuBlYmRRDcpCpsLke70T77dbxL1o7SVxzIzgqZJaoC3LmQ@kLJSsVs6ql7KIEJIxNy/KoxuTnBdox@b9K5KME6lT8fZjg3YAC9edcVIqmQgUbb0tk5jGkR97EqCXRpJlD3QC8Z3VVuOYJHud8AqtrejeVAjIdi/1atWTG3RFrotT2xDcJNkKUfwNe3AaXSgO8AiP8Rf8FU9W55SIgzDvtbHhT7SYIQJLihb9JQV4/jQklSir2iMURuoKUQiFKoXzMjtxNrRgtKTPMHwNBUtJsS8QhL8zqQTSdkXxJhIkAKydvo6CGE4NiQ/h2l5t57xc7mS2X7eJEvq1yhij9UT@P3TOaG/DFJufal7VToER1S@jwwM3UeZpbx0zFVoA4kwPMpjTFuDQUDL1uCfW2K5kcbyWbSD9q1zQ2QapNpLA5oC7h40G7gNXCaeEdWX6AeN9EAngX4qG4empX0fa6l5ah3qwPp//yo8ALmFuz7uRqhKmTuq@OUrYrl3@86jjcOoPFXZXTRgL4GTuQS2pTanLxjTZ7Jps7Eyr5Xu6cQ24KxmieFl9vxcfKjYDz@/80gu0Phb@LO81qeX2hD5cbrcgCKbTaT4ej4sgmEyOzuTY@wM)

First js post!

Comment: Not a big deal, but the typical etiquette is to wait a week or more before answering your own question.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 348 bytes

```javascript
a=>[[(P=f=>w=>f(w)&&1-w.some((n,i)=>n>1&!f(W=[...w],W[i]-=2))/2)(w=>w.some(n=>([p,q]=[q,(n-p-q)%3],1/q<0),p=q=0)),P(w=>w.some(n=>n%3)),],[w=>w.some(n=>n&-3)],[w=>w.some((n,i)=>i%8==1^n>0),w=>w.some((n,i)=>0<i&i<8^n>0)]].some(([i,I=i])=>i(n`m`)+i(n`p`)+i(n`s`)+I(n`z`)<1,n=t=>[...a.matchAll(`\\d(?=\\d*${t})`)].map(i=>s[i]++,s=Array(12).fill(0))&&s)
```

Passed all testcases. Though it may still be buggy. Comment any failed testcases, and I will try to fix them.

```javascript
a=>[[
  // given count of each tiles in same suit
  // return 1 if it is not a valid hand
  // return 0.5 if it is a valid hand with a pair
  // return 0 if it is a valid hand without a pair
  (P=f=>w=>f(w)&&1-w.some((n,i)=>n>1&!f(W=[...w],W[i]-=2))/2)
  // for m, p, s
   (w=>w.some(n=>([p,q]=[q,(n-p-q)%3],1/q<0),p=q=0)),
  // for z
  P(w=>w.some(n=>n%3)),
],[
  // for 7 pairs rule
  w=>w.some(n=>n&-3)
],[
  // for 13 orphan rule
  w=>w.some((n,i)=>i%8==1^n>0),
  w=>w.some((n,i)=>0<i&i<8^n>0)
]].some(([i,I=i])=>i(n`m`)+i(n`p`)+i(n`s`)+I(n`z`)<1,
  // Parse `112233456666m` -> `[0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
  n=t=>[...a.matchAll(`\\d(?=\\d*${t})`)].map(i=>s[i]++,s=Array(12).fill(0))&&s
);
```